# Catchable fatal error: And what is it?

Tags: mysqli

```html
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root");
 if (!$con){
  die("X");
 }
 
 $select=mysqli_select_db("$con","template1");
 
 if (!$select){
  die("XX");
 }
 
?>
```

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\login.php on line 7

So basically it is just a try out however i get the above error on my laptop and i would like to know why it happen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the line that needs to be fixed.

```
$select=mysqli_select_db("$con","template1");
```

By doing `"$con"` you're trying to convert `$con` to string. Just remove the quotes.

```
$select=mysqli_select_db($con,"template1");
```

Comment: However if i do so I will get a warning state:


Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\login.php on line 7.

Is it something ignoreable?